# 405 method not allowed when trying to upload a file to process on AWS S3 using Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I have created a Flask API which gets an Excel file from the user, runs a few operations on the data, and let's the user download the updated file. It is running fine on the local server. However, when I tried to run it on the AWS S3 bucket, it throws an error "405 Method Not Allowed" for "POST" operation.

My index.html looks like this:

```
<html>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>FILE INPUT</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for = "inputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" name="inputFile">
            </div>
            <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Download Results </button>
            </br>
        </form>  
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the flask file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file
from io import BytesIO
import jsonify
import traceback
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['inputFile']
        file.save(file.filename)
        return process(file.filename)


def process(filename):

    #
    ###  DO DATA(PANDAS) OPERATIONS  ###
    #


    return send_file(output, attachment_filename=name+'.xlsx', as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How do I make it run on S3? I tried updating the bucket policy to accept POST requests but that does not seem to help.

Comment: I don't see any code here that makes a `POST` request to S3... and it isn't clear to me what you mean by "run on S3" since you can't run code on S3.  Are you putting this index.html on a bucket and trying to post to the bucket from the browser?  If so, where is the python code running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting your Python code in the wrong AWS service, what you need is to deploy it on **Elastic beanstalk**. S3 is meant for storing static files like .html, .css or .js.

In this nice tutorial from the [official AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html), you can find what you need. Also, remember to have all the permissions you may need granted to not get a 403 error.